# Drop down menu doesn't display

Tags: html, css

What to do to display hidden drop down menu? It doesn't show after hovering. I don't know how to continue nor any detail to add. By the way I don't have much experience with JS so far.

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: arial;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #bf7500;
}

ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
}

ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

ul ul li a {
    color: black;
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
     <li><a href="one">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="two">Two</a></li>
     <li><a href="three">Three</a></li>
     <li><a href="four">Four</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Ay</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Bee</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Cee</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dee</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use javascript? (I think it will be much easier and prettier code..)

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply change

```
ul ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

To:

```
ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

This identifies the parent menu item (`ul li`) when it's being hovered on (`:hover`), and then shows the child menu (the final `ul`).